# Figuring out how to web scrape with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape the data in the Table with "Periods" and "percent per annum" (Table 4) as Columns in the [URL](http://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/browseTable.do?node=qview&SERIES_KEY=165.YC.B.U2.EUR.4F.G_N_A.SV_C_YM.SR_30Y&trans=N):

My code is as follows, but I think I am getting confused as to how to refer to the row just above the first date and corresponding number and hence get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'` in the line `row_name = row.findNext('td.header_units').getText()`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2 

url = "http://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/browseTable.do?node=qview&SERIES_KEY=165.YC.B.U2.EUR.4F.G_N_A.SV_C_YM.SR_30Y"

content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

desired_table = soup.findAll('table')[4]

# Find the columns you want data from
headers1 = desired_table.findAll('td.header_units')
headers2 = desired_table.findAll('td.header')
desired_columns = []
for th in headers1: #I'm just working with `headers1` currently to see if I have the right idea
    desired_columns.append([headers1.index(th), th.getText()])

# Iterate through each row grabbing the data from the desired columns
rows = desired_table.findAll('tr')

for row in rows[1:]:
    cells = row.findAll('td')
    row_name = row.findNext('td.header_units').getText()
    for column in desired_columns:
        print(cells[column[0]].text.encode('ascii', 'ignore'), row_name.encode('ascii', 'ignore'), column[1].encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```

Thank You

Comment: Do you mean `print(soup.find("table", {"class":"tablestats"}).text)`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I used the line `print(cells[column[0]].text.encode('ascii', 'ignore'), row_name.encode('ascii', 'ignore'), column[1].encode('ascii', 'ignore'))` with another code and it worked. However, the line you suggested could work too I guess.

Comment: that is the data you want yes?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks. The above code with the change you suggested works? Its strange, I seem to be getting the same Error that I had previously . Do you think this could be because I am running this on an IPython Notebook?

Comment: That should not matter,  I only get an error using your code

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks. So just to check again, the above code I posted with only the change from `print(cells[column[0]].text.encode('ascii', 'ignore'), row_name.encode('ascii', 'ignore'), column[1].encode('ascii', 'ignore'))` to `print(soup.find("table", {"class":"tablestats"}).text)` works fine?

Comment: it prints all the text, to get each individually you need to add a `find_all("td")` to find then extract the text, what output do you want?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I would actually like to just get the Dates and their corresponding numbers in the other column and their respective column titles as the output. However, for some reason even though the same code appears to be working for you, I appear to be having an issue with it. I keep getting the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'` which I described above. Do you know why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will put all the elements in tuples as pairs:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get(
    "http://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/browseTable.do?node=qview&SERIES_KEY=165.YC.B.U2.EUR.4F.G_N_A.SV_C_YM.SR_30Y")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

data = iter(soup.find("table", {"class": "tablestats"}).find("td", {"class": "header"}).find_all_next("tr"))


headers = (next(data).text, next(data).text)
table_items =  [(a.text, b.text) for ele in data for a, b in [ele.find_all("td")]]

for a, b in table_items:
    print(u"Period={}, Percent per annum={}".format(a, b if b.strip() else "null"))
```

Output:

```
Period=2015-06-09, Percent per annum=1.842026
Period=2015-06-08, Percent per annum=1.741636
Period=2015-06-07, Percent per annum=null
Period=2015-06-06, Percent per annum=null
Period=2015-06-05, Percent per annum=1.700042
Period=2015-06-04, Percent per annum=1.667431
```

Comment: This is great! Thank You. However, I am now trying to apply this same idea to a new page and was wondering where I am going wrong after making what I think are the necessary adjustments. I've edited my question to reflect this. Thank You.

Comment: @PadraicCunnigham Sorry, I'll just start a new question.

Comment: @user131983, no worries, if you add the url here I will have a look in a bit

Comment: @PadraicCunnigham Thank you. The URL is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764274/attributeerror-when-extracting-data-from-a-url-in-python

Comment: @user131983, the problem is the elements have different names