# AttributeError when extracting data from a URL in Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am using the code below to try an extract the data at the table in this [URL](http://www.federalreserve.gov/econresdata/researchdata/feds200628_1.html). However, I get the following error message:

```
Error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'`in 
the line `data = iter(soup.find("table", {"class": 
"tablestats"}).find("th", {"class": "header"}).find_all_next("tr"))`
```

My code is as follows:

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import requests

 r = requests.get(
 "http://www.federalreserve.gov/econresdata/researchdata/feds200628_1.html")
 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

 data = iter(soup.find("table", {"class": "tablestats"}).find("th", {"class": "header"}).find_all_next("tr"))


 headers = (next(data).text, next(data).text)
 table_items =  [(a.text, b.text) for ele in data for a, b in [ele.find_all("td")]]

 for a, b in table_items:
     print(u"Date={}, Maturity={}".format(a, b if b.strip() else "null"))
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


r = requests.get(
    "http://www.federalreserve.gov/econresdata/researchdata/feds200628_1.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

 # column headers
 h = data.find_all("th", scope="col")
 # get all the tr tags after the headers
 final = [[t.th.text] + [ele.text for ele in t.find_all("td")] for t in h[-1].find_all_next("tr")]
 headers = [th.text for th in h]
```

The final out list is all the rows in individual lists:

```
[['2015-06-05', '4.82039691', '-4.66420959', '-4.18904598', 
'-3.94541434', '1.1477', '2.9361', '3.3588', '0.6943', '1.5881',
 '2.3034', '2.7677', '3.0363', '3.1801', '3.2537', '3.2930', '3.3190', 
'3.3431', '3.3707', '3.4038', '3.4428', '3.4871', '3.5357', '3.5876',
 '3.6419', '3.6975', '3.7538', '3.8100', '3.8656', '3.9202', '3.9734',
 '4.0250', '4.0748', '4.1225', '4.1682', '4.2117', '4.2530', '4.2921',
 '0.3489', '0.7464', '1.1502', '1.4949', '1.7700', '1.9841', '2.1500', 
 '2.2800', '2.3837', '2.4685', '2.5396', '2.6006', '2.6544', '2.7027', 
 '2.7469', '2.7878', '2.8260', '2.8621', '2.8964', '2.9291', '2.9603',
 '2.9901', '3.0187', '3.0461', '3.0724', '3.0976', '3.1217', '3.1448',
 '3.1669', '3.1881', '0.3487', '0.7469', '1.1536', '1.5039', '1.7862',      
 '2.0078', '2.1811', '2.3179', '2.4277', '2.5181', '2.5943', '2.6603', 
 '2.7190', '2.7722', '2.8215', '2.8677', '2.9117', '2.9538', '2.9944', 
 '3.0338', '3.0721', '3.1094', '3.1458', '3.1814', '3.2161', '3.2501',
 '3.2832', '3.3156', '3.3472', '3.3781', '1.40431658', '9.48795888'], 
 ['2015-06-04', '4.64953424', '-4.52780982', '-3.98051369', 
 ......................................
```

The headers:

```
['BETA0', 'BETA1', 'BETA2', 'BETA3', 'SVEN1F01', 'SVEN1F04', 'SVEN1F09', 'SVENF01', 'SVENF02', 'SVENF03', 'SVENF04', 'SVENF05', 'SVENF06', 'SVENF07', 'SVENF08', 'SVENF09', 'SVENF10', 'SVENF11', 'SVENF12', 'SVENF13', 'SVENF14', 'SVENF15', 'SVENF16', 'SVENF17', 'SVENF18', 'SVENF19', 'SVENF20', 'SVENF21', 'SVENF22', 'SVENF23', 'SVENF24', 'SVENF25', 'SVENF26', 'SVENF27', 'SVENF28', 'SVENF29', 'SVENF30', 'SVENPY01', 'SVENPY02', 'SVENPY03', 'SVENPY04', 'SVENPY05', 'SVENPY06', 'SVENPY07', 'SVENPY08', 'SVENPY09', 'SVENPY10', 'SVENPY11', 'SVENPY12', 'SVENPY13', 'SVENPY14', 'SVENPY15', 'SVENPY16', 'SVENPY17', 'SVENPY18', 'SVENPY19', 'SVENPY20', 'SVENPY21', 'SVENPY22', 'SVENPY23', 'SVENPY24', 'SVENPY25', 'SVENPY26', 'SVENPY27', 'SVENPY28', 'SVENPY29', 'SVENPY30', 'SVENY01', 'SVENY02', 'SVENY03', 'SVENY04', 'SVENY05', 'SVENY06', 'SVENY07', 'SVENY08', 'SVENY09', 'SVENY10', 'SVENY11', 'SVENY12', 'SVENY13', 'SVENY14', 'SVENY15', 'SVENY16', 'SVENY17', 'SVENY18', 'SVENY19', 'SVENY20', 'SVENY21', 'SVENY22', 'SVENY23', 'SVENY24', 'SVENY25', 'SVENY26', 'SVENY27', 'SVENY28', 'SVENY29', 'SVENY30', 'TAU1', 'TAU2']
```

Comment: @PadraicCunnigham Thank You. However, with the code you provided I get the Error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`.

Comment: It gets all the table data for me, each row in individual lists, version of bs4?

Comment: @PadraicCunnigham I have the 3.2 version. Should I install a newer version?

Comment: yes, the latest is > 4.3, also what parser are you using?

Comment: @PadraicCunnigham Can I just install the latest version or would I need to delete version 3.2 before installing it? And I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: No, just `pip install -U beautifulsoup` to upgrade

Comment: @PadraicCunnigham Yes. It did. Thank You. I will not attempt to convert the headers and lists into a DataFrame.

Comment: No worries, that will be easy now the data is separated. You have the column names already to pass, then just pass the lists as the rows

Comment: Actually you will have one problem, make sure to give the dates a header, `headers.insert(0,"dates");df = pd.DataFrame(final,columns=headers)`, if you want to save to to a csv `df.to_csv("test.csv",sep="\t")`

Comment: @PadraicCunnigham Sorry to bring this up again. I was just wondering in the code in your Answer what you took `data` to be, as it hasn't been defined there? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues in your code.

1. There is no table with class 'tablestats'.
2. There are no 'th' fields with class 'header'.
3. Following line-

   table_items =  [(a.text, b.text) for ele in data for a, b in [ele.find_all("td")]]

doesnt return just 2 values, so cant assign to a, b