# AttributeError when scraping data from URL via Python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am using the code below to try an extract the data from the table in [this URL](http://www.federalreserve.gov/econresdata/researchdata/feds200628_1.html). I asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764274/attributeerror-when-extracting-data-from-a-url-in-python) and got an Answer for it. However, despite the code from the Answer working at that time I've now come to realize that `data` in the code hasn't been defined and hence the code below results in the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` in the line `final = [[t.th.text] + [ele.text for ele in t.find_all("td")] for t in h[-1].find_all_next("tr")]`. I have asked the user what `data` is, but I haven't been able to figure it out myself and was therefore hoping for some help in this regard.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from itertools import islice
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get(
    "http://www.federalreserve.gov/econresdata/researchdata/feds200628_1.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

h = data.find_all("th", scope="col") #Issue
final = [[t.th.text] + [ele.text for ele in t.find_all("td")] for t in h[-1].find_all_next("tr")]
headers = [th.text for th in h]

headers.insert(0,"dates")
df = pd.DataFrame(final,columns=headers)

print df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from itertools import islice

r = requests.get(
    "http://www.federalreserve.gov/econresdata/researchdata/feds200628_1.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

data = soup.find('table', attrs={'rules': 'all'})
h = data.find_all("th", scope="col") #Issue
final = [[t.th.text] + [ele.text for ele in t.find_all("td")] for t in h[-1].find_all_next("tr")]
headers = [th.text for th in h]
```

Comment: Thank You. However, I still get the Error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` in the line `final = [[t.th.text] + [ele.text for ele in t.find_all("td")] for t in h[-1].find_all_next("tr")`. Do you know why this might be

Comment: Are you sure you copied it properly? I just tried it and its working perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, its exactly the same. Do you think the version of `beautifulsoup` or Python could be having an impact?

Comment: Try using htmllib. First install it as `pip install html5lib`. Then use it to generate the soup - `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')`